# Kubuntu 18.10 Notifications Don't Show Up

Tags: kubuntu, notification

None of my Desktop pop-up notifications show up. I'm running Kubuntu 18.10 and KDE 5.13.5.

Any ideas on the issue?

Comment: Perhaps they're disabled? System Settings > Notifications > Other notifications?

Comment: No, it's enabled @DKBose

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you don't have Notification widget anywhere on your desktop. In my experience, notifications wouldn't show up, unless you add Notification widget in system tray panel or on desktop, or wherever it suits you.